# Current URL hashchange event append new hash to target URL and link out to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, window.location, hashchange

I have a page ex: test123.com/go#1 on that page if the hash changes ex: test123.com/go#2 I'd like to append the new hash value to a target URL and link out to it: test123.com/gopage2#2

Here's the code I've tried so far:

```
var url = window.location.href;
var res = url.split("#");
var hash = "#" + res[1];
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  window.location = 'test123.com/gopage2' + hash;
});
```

When the hash changes nothing happens... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you meant to update `url`, `res`, and `hash` in the event handler, and use the hash in the new URL, try this:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  var url = window.location.href;
  var res = url.split("#");
  var hash = "#" + res[1];
  window.location = 'test123.com/gopage' + res[1] + hash;
});
```